# How do I parse through a text file using Python to retrieve specific values?

Tags: python, parsing

In a text file, I have thousands of lines with this general format, here are the first few:

```
2   usfptotnap101a  \vol\vol0   \vol\vol0   -2147184536 Different Security Type
2   usfptotnap101a  \vol\vol0\etc   \vol\vol0\etc   -2147184538 Pruned. Different security type
2   usfptotnap101a  \vol\ibd_tot101a_185282 \vol\ibd_tot101a_185282\Shared\MA_REGLL\Project Five    1340    The inherited access control list (ACL) or access control entry (ACE) could not be built.
2   usfptotnap101a  \vol\fi_psc101a_201792  \vol\fi_psc101a_201792\Shared\Global Markets Americas Supervisory Team-REPORTS\Development  1340    The inherited access control list (ACL) or access control entry (ACE) could not be built.
2   usfptotnap101a  \vol\ops_tot101a_185457 \vol\ops_tot101a_185457\CollateralMgmt\collateral management\PIMCO TBA_TEST\GL Test 1340    The inherited access control list (ACL) or access control entry (ACE) could not be built.
2   usfptotnap101a  \vol\ops_tot101a_185457 \vol\ops_tot101a_185457\CollateralMgmt\collateral management\PIMCO TBA_TEST\2013    1340    The inherited access control list (ACL) or access control entry (ACE) could not be built.
2   usfptotnap101a  \vol\ops_tot101a_185457 \vol\ops_tot101a_185457\CollateralMgmt\collateral management\PIMCO TBA_TEST\Interest\2013\December Interest 1340    The inherited access control list (ACL) or access control entry (ACE) could not be built.
2   usfptotnap101a  \vol\ops_tot101a_185457 \vol\ops_tot101a_185457\CollateralMgmt\collateral management\PIMCO TBA_TEST\Interest\2013\October Interest  1340    The inherited access control list (ACL) or access control entry (ACE) could not be built.
2   usfptotnap101a  \vol\ops_tot101a_185457 \vol\ops_tot101a_185457\CollateralMgmt\collateral management\PIMCO TBA_TEST\Interest\2013\November Interest 1340    The inherited access control list (ACL) or access control entry (ACE) could not be built.
```

My goal is to collect the first path of each line (\vol\vol0, \vol\vol0\etc, \vol\ibd_tot101a_185282, etc.) as well as the last section of each line which are the error messages (Different Security Type, Different Security Type, The inherited access control list (ACL) or access control entry (ACE) could not be built, etc.)

I was thinking of parsing by the tabs (Note: the tabs look like a few spaces on stackoverflow) in between each section, but for the first two lines for example there isn't a tab after the error number so that ruins that plan.

In addition, I need to create in a dictionary of the path as well as the error message, including the number of occurrences of the combination of the two. For instance:

{'\vol\ops_tot101a_185457': {'Error 1': # of occurrences..., 'Error 2: # of occurrences...}

...where Error 1, Error 2, etc. can be a dictionary of the error messages mapping each error to a number.

I haven't been able to find any solutions that fit my specific problem, and I'm extremely new to coding/Python, but if you have any ideas/know of any modules that may help, please let me know! Thank you.

Comment: just read in each line, split it up into a list, then grab the paths you need

Comment: I see two paths in each line, you want only the first?

Comment: @SuperStew Thanks for your comment! Easier said than done if you're new to all of this. I know how to grab more than one section at a time ([2:] or [:3] or etc), but I'm not familiar with how to grab one at a time.

Comment: @aws_apprentice That is correct!

Comment: you sure this tab delimited?

Comment: @aws_apprentice Most lines are tab delimited after each section, but for some lines (see the first two) there is no tab after the number.

Comment: I don't see tabs in any line tbh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165304/discussion-between-ruth-and-aws-apprentice).

Answer (score 0):

Your deadline has probably passed. However, here is one, crude approach.

I split each line on white space (which involves no assumption that they are tabs), then I look for the number by itself which indicates the beginning of the error message using `int(item)` (which does involve the assumption that this is present in each and every line).

You could try this. If it croaks then you might be able to adjust it, or you might have to try something more sophisticated like a regex or pyparsing or some other parser.

```
with open('ruth.txt') as ruth:
    for line in ruth:
        items = line.rstrip().split()
        for i, item in enumerate(items[2:]):
            try:
                test = int(item)
                err = ' '.join(items[i+3:])
                break
            except:
                pass
        print(items[2], err)
```

Result:

```
\vol\vol0 Different Security Type
\vol\vol0\etc Pruned. Different security type
\vol\ibd_tot101a_185282 The inherited access control list (ACL) or access control entry (ACE) could not be built.
\vol\fi_psc101a_201792 The inherited access control list (ACL) or access control entry (ACE) could not be built.
\vol\ops_tot101a_185457 The inherited access control list (ACL) or access control entry (ACE) could not be built.
\vol\ops_tot101a_185457 The inherited access control list (ACL) or access control entry (ACE) could not be built.
\vol\ops_tot101a_185457 The inherited access control list (ACL) or access control entry (ACE) could not be built.
\vol\ops_tot101a_185457 The inherited access control list (ACL) or access control entry (ACE) could not be built.
\vol\ops_tot101a_185457 The inherited access control list (ACL) or access control entry (ACE) could not be built.
```